# Hide/Show Google Maps markers (groups) by radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I found an interesting example of showing markers groups using checkboxes:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769075/hide-show-google-maps-markers-based-on-their-category-or-group/77015643?answertab=trending#tab-top)

But sometimes one place has several categories (e.g. burgers, pizzeria etc.) and this results in several icons in one place (one for burger, one for pizzeria etc.).

I replaced the checkboxes with radio buttons and only one category can be selected. Unfortunately, clicking on a category does not remove previously shown markers. I tried several methods but nothing worked.

Is it possible to hide all visible markers after clicking on a category and close the (possibly) open information window, and only then show markers **only** from the clicked category?

Modified code (with radio buttons) here:

```
$(window).load(function (){

  var places={
    restaurant:{
      label:'restaurants',
      //the category may be default-checked when you want to
      //uncomment the next line
      //checked:true,
      icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png' ,
      items: [
              ['Melt Bar and Grill', 41.485345, -81.799047],
              ['Sloane Pub', 41.486182, -81.824178],
              ['Spitfire Salon', 41.479670, -81.768430],
              ['Mahall\'s', 41.476989, -81.781094],
              ['Szechwan Garden', 41.485615, -81.787890]
             ]
    },
    park:{
      label:'parks',
      //the category may be default-checked when you want to
      //uncomment the next line
      checked:true,
      icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/boost-marker-mapview.png',
      items: [
              ['Lakewood Park', 41.494457, -81.797605],
              ['Madison Park', 41.476969, -81.781929],
              ['Tuland Park', 41.464052, -81.788041]
             ]
    }  
  },
  map = new google.maps.Map(
              document.getElementById('map'), 
              {
                zoom: 14,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.485345, -81.799047),
              }
            ),
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
  
  // a  div where we will place the buttons
  ctrl=$('<div/>').css({background:'#fff',
                        border:'1px solid #000',
                        padding:'4px',
                        margin:'2px',
                        textAlign:'center'
                       });
  
  
  //now loop over the categories
  $.each(places,function(c,category){
    
    //a checkbox fo the category
    var cat=$('<input name="xxx" type="radio">',{type:'radio'}).change(function(){
       $(this).data('goo').set('map',(this.checked)?map:null);
    })
      //create a data-property with a google.maps.MVCObject
      //this MVC-object will do all the show/hide for the category 
      .data('goo',new google.maps.MVCObject)
      .prop('checked',!!category.checked)
      
      //this will initialize the map-property of the MVCObject
      .trigger('change')
      
      //label for the checkbox
      .appendTo($('<div/>').css({whiteSpace:'nowrap',textAlign:'left'}).appendTo(ctrl))
      .after(category.label);
      
      //loop over the items(markers)
      $.each(category.items,function(m,item){
         var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:new google.maps.LatLng(item[1],item[2]),
                title:item[0],
                icon:category.icon
              });
         
         //bind the map-property of the marker to the map-property
         //of the MVCObject that has been stored as checkbox-data 
         marker.bindTo('map',cat.data('goo'),'map');
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
            infowindow.setContent(item[0]);
            infowindow.open(map,this);
         });
      });
        
  });
 
 //use the buttons-div as map-control 
 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(ctrl[0]);
}
);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cyberjarek/a3pu2bkm/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be tempted to create an `Object literal` to store references to every marker added to the map but keyed by category. With the markers so grouped it should be easy to remove a whole category's worth or markers when a new category is selected.

```
$(window).load(function (){

    // global object to store marker references
    var markers={};
    
    var places={
        restaurant:{
          label:'restaurants',
          icon:'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png' ,
          items:[
              ['Melt Bar and Grill', 41.485345, -81.799047],
              ['Sloane Pub', 41.486182, -81.824178],
              ['Spitfire Salon', 41.479670, -81.768430],
              ['Mahall\'s', 41.476989, -81.781094],
              ['Szechwan Garden', 41.485615, -81.787890]
          ]
        },
        park:{
          label:'parks',
          checked:true,
          icon:'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/boost-marker-mapview.png',
          items:[
              ['Lakewood Park', 41.494457, -81.797605],
              ['Madison Park', 41.476969, -81.781929],
              ['Tuland Park', 41.464052, -81.788041]
          ]
        }  
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), 
      {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.485345, -81.799047),
      }
    ),
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),

    
    ctrl=$('<div/>').css({
        background:'#fff',
        border:'1px solid #000',
        padding:'4px',
        margin:'2px',
        textAlign:'center'
    });
    
    
    
    $.each( places, function( c, category ){
        if( !markers.hasOwnProperty( category ) ) markers[ category ]=[];
        
        
        var cat=$('<input name="xxx" type="radio">',{ type:'radio' } ).change( function(e){
            
            // remove markers from all categories prior to adding new
            markers[ category ].forEach(mkr=>mkr.setMap(null))
            
            $(this).data('goo').set('map',( this.checked ) ? map : null );
        })
            .data('goo',new google.maps.MVCObject)
            .prop('checked', !!category.checked )
            .trigger('change')
            .appendTo($('<div/>').css({ whiteSpace:'nowrap', textAlign:'left' } ).appendTo( ctrl ) )
            .after( category.label );
          
          
        //loop over the items(markers)
        $.each(category.items,function(m,item){
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:new google.maps.LatLng(item[1],item[2]),
                title:item[0],
                icon:category.icon
            });
            
            marker.bindTo('map',cat.data('goo'),'map');
            
            google.maps.event.addListener( marker,'click',function(){
                infowindow.setContent(item[0]);
                infowindow.open(map,this);
            });
            
            // add marker to global object, keyed by cateogry
            markers[ category ].push( marker )
        });
    });
    map.controls[ google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT ].push( ctrl[0] );
});
```

[Proof of concept](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/s3f8rnxm/5/)